# Static Repositories - Workaround

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, inversion-of-control

First, some background.  We have recently taken on a large MVC3 project.  The project was pretty much ready to go live some time ago, then the client decided they wanted to re-theme the whole website and add a load more functionality.  They employed us to re-theme the site, finish off the remaining functionality and deploy it.

Generally it is built using a very clear, ordered approach, with one repository for each database table and a clear service layer, however there are some oddities that are making me slightly uncomfortable.  The main oddity that keeps on nagging at me is that every single repository and service in the application is completely, 100% static (yes, including methods that write to the db).  Of course, this doesn't allow for unit testing, however a greater concern is the potential bottlenecks and threading issues that will cause when the application comes under a heavy load.  I am already seeing some unexplained delays in processing requests on the stage server, and that is with a trickle of testing traffic.

The application is so huge that rebuilding it to use IOC/instantiated-per-request repositories is pretty much out of the question.

What can I do to avoid potential threading issues upon deployment?  Could i use a connection pool and borrow a db connection each time a write needs to happen?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit - here is some of the code that creates an instance of the entity model.  Each static method calls this 'DemoEntities' method to obtain an instance of the entity model, which it then uses to execute the db commands.  I can see here that, though the method is static, it is actually checking the HttpRequest for a pre-existing instance and creating one if it doesn't already exist.  As such, I think we'll be ok.

```
   public static DemoEntities DemoEntities
   {
       get
       { 
           if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items["DemoEntities"] == null) 
           {
               HttpContext.Current.Items["DemoEntities"] = new DemoEntities(); 
           }
           return HttpContext.Current.Items["DemoEntities"] as DemoEntities;
       }
       set
       {
           if (HttpContext.Current != null)
               HttpContext.Current.Items["DemoEntities"] = value;
       }
   }
```

`

Pat

Comment: Could you show some code that exemplifies the threading issues and the bottlenecks of the solution? Besides I don't like the use of static classes in that way, just that wouldn't be issue. Maybe you can show what forms the state (static state) of the repositories (maybe the database connection? Datacontext?)

Comment: This code block seems to show an attempt at implementing the singleton pattern to make a per-thread instance and not a truly static object.  I am not sure that this is the optimal approach for a singleton, as nothing this being done to lock anything;  will it be "bad" if two demo entity instances get created on the same thread due to synchronization issues?  Also, why is it one per thread?

Answer (score 6):

I assume here that your repository classes only contain static methods, not any static state.

The benefit of stateless static classes is that they can be safely turned into regular classes with default parameterless constructors and no concerns over their life-span. It would then be a simple case to extract an interface for testing purposes.

Whenever you need to talk to a repository, simply instantiate one.

Unless the application is doing something with shared state during repository use, you should not need to be concerned about multi-threaded access. The database itself is responsible for handling many concurrent calls.

Currently all bottlenecks and threading issues are potential, sometimes our educated guesses at what could possibly go wrong are *themselves* wrong - especially so with multi-threading. The slow down might simply be because the database doesn't have the grunt to cope with too many requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it sounds like we might be ok in that case.  See the code I am about to post in Filburt's comment.